# How to use miniedit in mininet?. Can anyone suggest the commands

Tags: python, pip, sdn, mininet

I am not able to run the command $ sudo ~/mininet/examples/miniedit.py  in mininet.When I type that command to use miniedit the output comes as Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `"./mininet/examples/miniedit.py"`, line 63, in 
    from mininet.log import info, debug, warn, setLogLevel
ImportError: No module named mininet.log

Comment: Don't use `sudo` to run scripts in your `$HOME`. Actually don't use `sudo` for anything, except when you know it's really needed.

Comment: Try `PYTHONPATH=~/mininet ~/mininet/examples/miniedit.py`. Or better yet create a [tag:virtualenv] and install `mininet` into it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute miniedit.py  from remote terminal "that has visualization" using ssh .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, all I did was change the default file path to desktop `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mininet/examples` path to `Desktop` and it works